# Is this a good setup for a probability based random number generator for C?

Tags: c, random

In my opinion, I feel like this is definitely not achieving what it's *supposed* to do. I was needing a random number generator based off probability to determine a winner of a race. So Runner A has a 40% chance of winning, for example.

```
    //function definition
void createDogs(DOGS* dogList) {
    //adding info the the dogInfo struct
    strcpy(dogList[0].dogName, "Easy Rex"); //dog 1
    dogList[0].odds = 40;
    dogList[0].payoutMultiplier = 2;
    strcpy(dogList[1].dogName, "Worried Bud"); //dog 2
    dogList[1].odds = 10;
    dogList[1].payoutMultiplier = 5;
    strcpy(dogList[2].dogName, "Money Ace"); //dog 3
    dogList[2].odds = 8;
    dogList[2].payoutMultiplier = 10;
    strcpy(dogList[3].dogName, "Lucky Lady"); //dog 4
    dogList[3].odds = 15;
    dogList[3].payoutMultiplier = 15;
    strcpy(dogList[4].dogName, "Cash Dawg"); //dog 5
    dogList[4].odds = 1;
    dogList[4].payoutMultiplier = 50;
    strcpy(dogList[5].dogName, "Unlucky Brutus"); //dog 6
    dogList[5].odds = 4;
    dogList[5].payoutMultiplier = 20;
    strcpy(dogList[6].dogName, "Gamble Champ"); //dog 7
    dogList[6].odds = 8;
    dogList[6].payoutMultiplier = 10;
    strcpy(dogList[7].dogName, "Nothing Chewy"); //dog 8
    dogList[7].odds = 10;
    dogList[7].payoutMultiplier = 5;
    strcpy(dogList[8].dogName, "Easy Roxy"); //dog 9
    dogList[8].odds = 13;
    dogList[8].payoutMultiplier = 3;
}//end createDogs
```

So here's where I put the probability, under the "odds", then here is where I implement it. Thinking that the odds is the percentage so grabbing the random number from 0 to that "percentage" and then compare them with the others to determine the winner.

```
//function definition
void dogRace(DOGS* dogList, DATA* raceInfo, int counter) {
    int numberRolled[NO_OF_DOGS];
    int i, moneyWon;
    int biggestNumber, position = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    printf("\nAnd the race is on!");
    pause(5);
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_DOGS; i++) { //assigns a number to each dog based on its odds
        numberRolled[i] = (rand() % dogList[i].odds);
    }//end for
    biggestNumber = numberRolled[0];
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_DOGS; i++) { //determines which dog won (>number rolled)
        if (biggestNumber < numberRolled[i]) {
                biggestNumber = numberRolled[i];
                position = i;
            }//end if
    }//end for
}
```

Technically it works, but I feel as it's not really the right way to do it- let me know if there is a better way to do this because my textbooks do no give any example for this type of problem. I've also tried googling/youtubing it and had no luck finding for what I was looking for.

Comment: What  is `odds`? This is a chance out of how much? If, say, out of `100`, then you should roll a number from `0` to `100` and compare your `odds` to it.

Comment: "odds" does not usually mean %.  Odds of 40:1, for example, is 2.5% chance of winning.

Comment: Then it *should* be converted to uniform scale first.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so how would I compare the odds to it, with like let's say dogList[1].odds > rolledNumber? or something like that?

Comment: @stark. Yes i know, but I just called it odds in the program cuz it's much shorter than like percentage or winChance

Comment: The `payoutMultiplier` is more related to betting odds. Is your `odds` supposed to mean something "performance record"?

Comment: @WeatherVane payoutMultiplier is related to how much is multipled to the user's bet made on a dog so if they placed a bet on dog 1 and it won, they would receive 2x the amount of that bet as money won. odds is percentage chance on winning. At least that's what I tried to have it do.

Comment: @CodedRoses Yes (but vice versa). If `odds` is percentage, then you roll a number up to `100` an compare `odds < rolledNumber`. So say your odds are 30%, and your chance to roll a number less than 30 is %30. So `odds < rolledNumber` will give you the winning condition.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Yes, I was just thinking that after I reread what I said. Okay, going to try that out. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If "odds" is a percentage probability of winning, they ought to add up to 100, but they actually add up to more than that in `createDogs` above. In my answer, I just used the sum of "odds" instead of 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cumulative odds:

- S = sum of odds of dogs 0 to number of dogs - 1
- R = random integer from 0 to S-1
- i = 0
- while i < number of dogs and dog[i].odds <= R: R = R - dog[i].odds, i = i + 1

```
//function definition
void dogRace(DOGS* dogList, DATA* raceInfo, int counter) {
    int i, moneyWon, position;
    int sum_of_odds = 0;
    int rolled;
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_DOGS; i++) {
        sum_of_odds += dogList[i].odds;
    }
    // Note, usually you should only call srand() once in a program.
    srand(time(0));
    printf("\nAnd the race is on!");
    pause(5);
    rolled = randInt(sum_of_odds);
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_DOGS; i++) {
        if (dogList[i].odds > rolled)
            break;
        rolled -= dogList[i].odds;
    }//end for
    position = i;
}
```

The `randInt` function called above is given below:

```
// random integer from 0 to n-1 (for n in range 1 to RAND_MAX+1u)
int randInt(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int x = (RAND_MAX + 1u) / n;
    unsigned int limit = x * n;
    int s;
    do {
        s = rand();
    } while (s >= limit);
    return s / x;
}
```

The above is preferable to using `rand() % n` because it removes any bias in the likely case that `RAND_MAX+1` is not a multiple of `n`. Also, some implementations of `rand()` produce not very random sequences for `rand() % n` so it is better to use the quotient of division rather than the remainder.

Comment: This seems like it makes the first dog win every time, if the first dog rolls a number lower than it's odds it breaks away from the for loop and is determined winner, without giving the other dogs to have a possible chance of rolling a number within it's odds that may be higher than the first dog's roll.

Comment: I've added this in, and I'm getting weird results... For the first 10 games, the first dog won, and then for the next 20+ games it has been the last dog in my set list winning it. I don't know if that's just the *odds* being odds, but i don't know.

Comment: @CodedRoses Are you calling `srand(time(0))` every time? That call probably shouldn't be in this function. Generally, `srand()` should be called once in the entire execution of the program. (I left the call in because it was in your original function.)

Comment: @CodedRoses The code determines the winner from a single random number with the "odds" weighting the outcome. (Higher "odds" means more likely to win. Note that this is opposite to the usual betting definition of "odds", which is more like your payout multiplier.)